# How to prove that the functions which map from real numbers to rational numbers is not possibly continuous without using the IVT?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

### I can make up a non-constant function f(x) like this: its domain is an interval, for example [0,1], and its range is totally composed of many rational numbers.
The problem is: If I pick the range very carefully, it seems that it is possible that every  $\lim_{t\rightarrow\ x}f(t)$could equal to some rational number for every x, I mean for any sequence {tn} converging to x, just make sure that f(tn) would not converge to a irrational number, which means that this is a continuous function!
I know by the Intermediate Value Theorem, it is impossible. But how can I prove this impossiblity without using the IVT, or say how can I prove that the idea picking range process which seeems really feasible is impossible?

Edit: The intuition of this problem comes from this: when we first learn the continuity of functions, we always relate it with a non-liftinghand curve which looks very compact. But if I use so big enough amount of rational numbers that the graphy looks almost the same with the one of real numbers because there is an infinity of rational numbers (less than real numbers though).
If I want to prove this statement is wrong by using Reductio ad Absurdum, namely asume that there exist a function like that, I mean every $\lim_{t\rightarrow\ x}f(t)$ equals to some rational number, how can I find the contradiction from the perspective of limits rather than the macro things like the IVT?

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us just how you will "pick the range very carefully" to guarantee the rational limits you need we may be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use the connectedness of $[0,1]$ here, which is equivalent to IVT. After all, there *is* a nonconstant continuous function from e.g. $[0,1]\setminus\{{1\over 2}\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$, so as soon as we drop connectedness we can't prove the statement. We could of course try to *rephrase* the standard argument to avoid explicit appeal to IVT, but this wouldn't change its mathematical content.

Comment: Another interesting example is the Cantor function, but restricted to the complement of the Cantor set.  It is quite non-constant (in the sense that it takes every dyadic rational value in $[0,1]$), but still continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the statement you are trying to prove is correct. Consider the function $f(x)=r$ where $r$ is a rational number. This is a function from the reals to the rationals and it is certainly continuous. Do you mean to ask about a function from the reals *onto* the rationals - in which case, my example would fall short?

Comment: I mean it's a non-constant function because the range is composed by many rational numbers. And what I wanna supplement is that the intuition of this problem comes from this: we always draw a continuous function as a non-stop line which looks compact, but if the range is composed of enough big amount of rational numbers such that the line looks almost the same as composed of real numbers? How could you prove this is impossible?

Comment: Upvoting this answer just to cancel out the downvote.  It was written before the question was edited to remove this exception.